# Return Data using Stored Procedure in AdoDB PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server, stored-procedures, adodb-php

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 as my Database and I created a Stored Procedure that looks like this.

```
USE [DB_Question]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Check_ExamID]
@ExamID NVARCHAR(MAX)
as
SELECT * FROM TBL_ExamTimer WHERE ExamID = @ExamID
```

and here is my PHP code that suppost to be the target is to display data in my PHP site by using some criteria also.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php

    include('config.php');
    include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
    $db = ADONewConnection($dbdriver);
    $db->Connect($dsn, $username, $password);

    $procedure = $db->prepareSp('Check_ExamID');
    if (!$procedure)
    die ('Invalid or inaccessible stored procedure name');

    $parameter1Name = '@ExamID';
    $ok = $db->inParameter($procedure,$parameter1Name,'1234');
    $result = $db->execute($procedure);


?> 
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to display data where `ExamID =@ExamID` or `1234` for param of `@ExamID`

My Target here is to use my stored procedure to select data in my table and return it back in my php file but nothings happening. TYSM

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, the parameters must be strings passed by reference, so the correct syntax is:

```
$parameter1Name = '@ExamID';
$parameter1Value = '1234';

$ok = $db->inParameter($procedure,$parameter1Name,$parameter1Value);
$result = $db->execute($procedure);
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried, but if i use inParameter it isn´t right.
I have php 5.4.45, Adodb 5 and mssql 8.0
I write my code.

```
//connection
$conexion = &ADONewConnection('odbc_mssql');
$datos_sql = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=$nameServer;Database=$nameBD;";
$conexion -> Connect($datos_sql, $user, $password);
$procedure = $conexion ->prepareSP('Test');
//This is the in parameter
$paramName1='@articulo';
$paramValour1='90.27.05';
conexion ->inParameter($procedure,$paramName1,  $paramValour1);
if (!$procedure)
    die ('Invalid or inaccessible stored procedure name');
$result = $conexion ->execute($procedure) or die($conexion ->ErrorMsg());
while($r = $result->fetchRow())
    print_r($r);
```

Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] (@articulo VARCHAR(30))
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT Peso
    ,CodigoArticulo
FROM maestro_articulos
WHERE codigoarticulo LIKE @articulo;

RETURN
```

The error is:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The procedure 'Test'
> requires the parameter '@articulo', which was not specified.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.